# Delete files with specific extension except a particular file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delete-file

I have a folder which contains the following files:

[image]

How can I delete all files with extension .rst (File1.rst, File2.rst, File3.rst, File4.rst, File5.rst) except the file "index.rst" from a batch file.

I have tried this, but it's not working:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('D:\hfTools\Projects\Validation-Source\Docs\source /b "*.rst"') do @(if "%i" neq "index.rst" echo %i)
```

Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you put the missing `dir` command back in? and remove the seemingly unneeded `skip=1`? and obviously change `echo` to `del`? and preferably use `==` instead of `neq`? and more safely use the `/I` option with your `if` command? and then use `%%i` instead of `%i` as you're using a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to perform the task using the `ForFiles` command, `forfiles.exe`:

```batch-file
@%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe /P "D:\hfTools\Projects\Validation-Source\Docs\source" /M "*.rst" /C "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe /D /C If @IsDir==FALSE If /I Not @FName==0x22index0x22 Del /A /F @File"
```

---

Here's an example of how to perform the task using the `Dir` command:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
If Exist "D:\hfTools\Projects\Validation-Source\Docs\source\*.rst" (
    PushD "D:\hfTools\Projects\Validation-Source\Docs\source" && (
        For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "*.rst" ^
         ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /E /I /L ".rst" ^
         ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /I /L /V /X "index.rst"'
        ) Do Del /A /F "%%G"
        PopD
    )
)
```

---

My preference however would be to use the `Where` command, `where.exe`:

Example [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe ^
 "D:\hfTools\Projects\Validation-Source\Docs\source":"*.rst" ^
 ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /E /I /L /V "\index.rst"'
) Do Del /A /F "%%G"
```

You could even do that as a single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe "D:\hfTools\Projects\Validation-Source\Docs\source":"*.rst"^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /EILV "\index.rst"')Do @Del /A/F "%%G"
```

Or directly from a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) window:

```batch-file
For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %G In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe "D:\hfTools\Projects\Validation-Source\Docs\source":"*.rst"^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /EILV "\index.rst"')Do @Del /A/F "%G"
```

---

And for an off topic bonus, because for general use it seems easier; use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) instead:

```batch-file
Remove-Item -Path "D:\hfTools\Projects\Validation-Source\Docs\source\*.rst" -Exclude "index.rst" -Force
```

You could even run that using a one line batch file, if you really needed to:

```batch-file
@%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoP "RI 'D:\hfTools\Projects\Validation-Source\Docs\source\*.rst' -E 'index.rst' -Fo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
forfiles /M *.rst /C "cmd /c if @file!=index.rst del @file"
```

Explanation:

```
/M *.rst    # only consider *.rst
if ...      # @file is the filename as found by forfiles
            # != is this the correct way say "does not equal"?
```

Comment: sorry for asking,  where I should specify the directory where are located all these folders? Instead of /C?

Comment: You can add `/P <pathnme>`.

Comment: The code deletes index.rst, not the needed files (File1.rst, File2.rst) strange

Comment: forfiles /P D:\source /M *.rst /C "cmd /c if not @file=="index.rst" del @file"

Comment: != is not recognised

Comment: forfiles /P D:\source /M *.rst /C "cmd /c if not @file==\"index.rst\" del @file" (make sure you escape the " inside the command otherwise it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

You are actually quite close, you just forgot to double a few `%`-signs and you missed the `dir` command:

```cmd
rem // Change to target directory, because `dir /B` only returns pure file names:
pushd "D:\hfTools\Projects\Validation-Source\Docs\source" && (
    rem // Capture the output of `dir /B` and loop through the lines/files:
    for /f "delims= eol=|" %%i in ('
        dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*.rst"
    ') do @(
        rem // Check file name against predefined exception:
        if /I not "%%i"=="index.rst" (
            rem // Actually delete the currently iterated file:
            ECHO del "%%i"
        )
    )
    popd
)
```

Once you are satisfied with the output, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` command** to actually delete files.

Note that the pattern `*.rst` in the `dir /B` command line is actually checked against both [long and short file names](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-filenames.html) (if the latter is enabled), so it actually matches files whose extensions *begin with* `rst` (if applicable).

---

If the files to delete always match the pattern `File*.rst` you do not even need the `if` condition:

```cmd
rem // Change to target directory, because `dir /B` only returns pure file names:
pushd "D:\hfTools\Projects\Validation-Source\Docs\source" && (
    rem // Capture the output of `dir /B` and loop through the lines/files:
    for /f "delims= eol=|" %%i in ('
        dir /B /A:-D-H-S "File*.rst"
    ') do @(
        rem // Actually delete the currently iterated file:
        ECHO del "%%i"
    )
    popd
)
```

Comment: Be aware that `Dir` with `*.rst`, does not select files with only the case insensitive extension `.rst`. It selects all files with a file extension beginning with `.rst`. For that reason, in my provided `Dir` example, I used `findstr.exe` to specifically exclude that possibility. It may not be likely that you have any other files with extensions beginning with, _(there's none in your screenshot)_, but not matching `.rst`, but a robust script, especially one which deletes files, should not make assumptions.

Comment: Once a `FindStr` is introduced during the 'command' portion, it is more efficient to exclude the known name within that command, _(using another pipe to `FindStr`)_, than to do it using an `If` statement in the 'do' portion. In fact, I've been advised here before, that the single pipe to `FindStr` within the 'command' portion is more efficient than using an `If` statement in the 'do' portion.

Comment: You're right, @Compo, thanks! I edited my answer to mention the 8.3 names…

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using PowerShell. If you are on a supported version of Windows, PowerShell will be available. When you are confident that the correct files will be removed, remove the `-WhatIf` from the command.

```
Remove-Item -Path './*' -Include '*.rst' -Exclude 'index.rst' -WhatIf
```

Id you must do it from a cmd.exe (.bat file) script:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Remove-Item -Path './*' -Include '*.rst' -Exclude 'index.rst' -WhatIf"
```

Comment: Other than specifically using the `-Include` parameter lit, _which isn't technically needed here_, my answer already provided a [tag:powershell] example, along with how to run it from a [tag:batch-file].